# Apache Kafka Consumer stop consuming messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a problem with a Kafka Consumer.
I use new Kafka and new Consumer Java API. It is simplest Kafka and Zookeeper from [quickstart](http://kafka.apache.org/quickstart).

I start app and after my consumer has consume message from topic few times it stopped to receive.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;

public class MyKC{

    public MyKC(){
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");
        config.put("group.id", "default");
        config.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        config.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
        config.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        config.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(config);

        TopicPartition tp = new TopicPartition("connect-test", 0);
        List<TopicPartition> ltp = Arrays.asList(tp);
        consumer.assign(ltp);
        consumer.seekToEnd(ltp);
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records;

        while(true){
            records = consumer.poll(1000);
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
                System.out.println(record.value());
        }
    }
}
```

When i append into my code count number of messages:

```
while(true){
    records = consumer.poll(1000);
    System.out.print(records.count() + "; ");
}
```

I see that on every iteration consumer don't get posts. It look like this:

> 1; 1; 1; 0; 0; 30; 70; 1; 1; 21; 16; 2; 1; 1; 8; 49; 2; 1; 62; 35; 5; 11; 47; 2; 1; 1; 1; 1; 31; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; etc.

It may take a long time (above 5 min) or few seconds, but i have the same result every times.

When I restart the consumer, history repeat itself. I am sure that the messages continue to arrive in the topic in the amount of 100 per second.

Does anyone have any idea?

### Update

By the way, if i use the hight level consumer like description [on this page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example), this consumer have the same problem like previous, but it didn't take a messages from topic until i do not restart the kafka server.

The first consumer (simple) take a messages continue if i rebooted him, and not the server.

If i use the subscribe() method i must to reboot the kafka server if i want that consumer receive a messages.
If i use assign() method, i must reboot only my consumer and it will receive 
data some time.

### Update 2

Little more data about this.
If i set consumer configurations like this: `consumer.seekToBeginning(ltp);`
My consumer receive the messages without any problem all time till then reaches end of offset. Then consumer receiving messages more difficultly until it stoped.

If i set this setting in `consumer.seekToEnd(ltp);` consumer start receive the messages without problem first few seconds, and then gradually stoped.

May be problem any way related to offset of messages?

### Update 3

It is my answer for comment @fhussonnois.

Sorry, but level of my english won't let me read Javadoc on the fly. If i understand correctly description of this method, poll(Long.MAX_VALUE) make consumer keep waiting for 292 thousand years while we know that Kafka cluster recive the data in amount 100 per second.

Now i created my dirty-fix and i launched it on the test. it's look like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;

public class MyKC{

    private Properties config;
    private KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer;
    private TopicPartition tp;
    private List<TopicPartition> ltp;
    private ConsumerRecords<String, String> records;
    private long offset = 0;

    public MyKC(){
        config = new Properties();
        config.put("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");
        config.put("group.id", "default");
        config.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        config.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
        config.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        config.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

        consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(config);

        tp = new TopicPartition("connect-test", 0);
        ltp = Arrays.asList(tp);
        consumer.assign(ltp);
        consumer.seekToEnd(ltp);

        consume();
    }

    private void newConsumer(long offset){
        consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(config);
        consumer.assign(ltp);
        consumer.seek(tp, offset);
        consume();
    }

    private void restart(){
        offset = consumer.endOffsets(ltp).get(tp);
        consumer.close();
        consumer = null;
        newConsumer(offset);
    }

    public void consume(){

        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while (true) {
            records = consumer.poll(1000);

            if (records.count() != 0){
                time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records){
                    System.out.println(record.value());
                }
            } else {
                if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - time) >= 30000){
                    restart();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On this moment it's worked 2 hours and restarted himself 14 times.

After i will cancel this test, i will try your way. :)

Comment: You manually assign the partition 0 to your consumer. Is your topic has only one partition ? If it's not then it seems you have no message into partition 0. You should try to use the subscribe() method. BTW the property zookepper.connect is not required.

Comment: @fhussonnois, thank you, for your answer, but the problem still there is.
I used the 'discribe' command in console of Kafka server and i saw, that i have only one partition in my topic.

Comment: @fhussonnois I try to use subscribe() method with the same result.

Comment: @Valerity, is your Kafka cluster remote ? Try to use poll(Long.MAX_VALUE)

Comment: @fhussonnois My answer to you in Update 3.

Comment: @Valerity did you figure out the issue?

Comment: @neoeahit i'm afraid not. I still use the method i described in "Update 3". I just increase offset until i begin to receive messages again. I not found other way.